# ios: why does not self.navigationItem.title show the title, how can change the title?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I come across a strange issue

code :

```
- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Hello title";
}
```

and there is a navigation bar in the xib file.
the navigtion bar is show in the view after loaded.
however, "Hello title" does not show in the navigationbar.

so How can I change the navigationbar title ?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it a navigation Bar or a Navigation Controller?

Comment: sorry for my late reply. thanks for your help. neithor. a ViewController

Answer (score 10):

Try out this piece of code:

```
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"The Title";
```

Comment: For swift I had to add two exclamation points  self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "The Title";

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.title = @"Hello title";
```

Answer (score 0):

type this on view didload which where you the view' navigation
       `self.title = @"Hello title";`

Answer (score -2):

Try writing tis in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView=[self navigationItemTile:@"Hello Title"];
```

Or try in the `initWithNibname` method:

```
[self setTitle:@"Hello title"];
```